# Ruby on Rails: Help in foreign_key model validations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

It's my first time using foreign_key, and I don't relatively know how to create validation for it. The problem goes like this:

I am creating a chat request, and chat box app.

I have chatrequest model that goes like this.

```
chatrequest.rb
has_many :conversations
belongs_to :user
```

Next, I have a conversation model, which batch the users when he accepted the chat request.

```
conversation.rb
belongs_to :chatrequest
belongs_to :sender, foreign_key: "sender_id", class_name: "User"
belongs_to :recipient, foreign_key: "recipient_id", class_name: "User"
```

The logic is already working. I created a link_to function that combines creates the chat conversation model, which goes like this:

```html
<p>
<%= link_to 'Chat me', conversations_path(sender_id: current_user.id, recipient_id: @chatrequest.user.id, chatrequest_id: @chatrequest.id), method: 'POST' %>
</p>
```

Now, what I wanted to achieve is these 3 validations:

1. current_user != recipient_id (cannot accept request to self)
2. will not create unless current_user.id == sender_id
3. will not create unless chatrequest.user.id == recipient_id
   4.(OPTIONAL) make sure that current_user(sender) will accept sender_id(recipient) only ones.

Sorry if it is kinda hard, I really don't know what to do. If you have code snippets, please post it as well. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'd love to know if my approach worked if you found another way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can both create your own methods to validate pretty much anything as well as using ActiveRecord ones. If you make your own, you can do it the ugly way:

```
validate :conversation_is_valid

def conversation_is_valid
  errors.add(:recipient, "can't be the sender") if recipient_id != current_user
  errors.add(:sender, "needs to be the current user") if current_user.id == sender_id
  errors.add(:chatrequest, "user needs to be the recipient") if chatrequest.user.id == recipient_id
end
```

This will make sure all your requirements are checked and it won't persist if it's not true. Otherwise it'll notify you of errors. There are multiple ways of doing this, check the [Validations Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html)